# Error "The connection to the server was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm new to K8s. I'm configuring a K8s cluster on EC2 and I've started by installing docker, then started:

`systemclt start docker`

Installed kubeadm on the EC2 instance:

(https://v1-28.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl)

Initialized kubeadm:

`sudo kubeadm init`

Then as per the instructions there, ran:

`mkdir -p $HOME/.kube`
`sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config`
`sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`

It goes well, I ran kubectl get nodes and it shows the following output:

`[]# kubectl get nodes`

NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION ip-172-31-3-249.us-west-2.compute.internal NotReady control-plane 86s v1.28.7

After a few minutes, I tried

`[]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

and got the following error:

The connection to the server 172.31.3.249:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

really appreciate if someone can help with this!

i've tried this - https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/the-connection-to-the-server-host-6443-was-refused-did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port/552/5 but it didn't work for me.